# How do I select top rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have a code that outputs Department Names and their number of workers.

```
SELECT department_name,COUNT (employee_id) FROM EMPLOYEES  
JOIN DEPARTMENTS  
ON employees.department_id=departments.department_id
GROUP BY department_name 
ORDER BY count(employee_id) DESC
```

[image: Output]

I want to select the first three department names that have the largest number of workers. . When I  `WHERE`, I get three rows, but the output is not true.

```
SELECT department_name,COUNT (employee_id) FROM EMPLOYEES  
JOIN DEPARTMENTS  
ON employees.department_id=departments.department_id
WHERE rownum <= 4
GROUP BY department_name 
ORDER BY count(employee_id) DESC
```

[image: Output]

What can you recommend to me about this issue? Also, I will use this query in a PL/SQL block.
THANKS!

Comment: All explained here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rownum clause happens before the sort. You can either use

```
fetch first 3 rows only
```

**after** the order by clause, if using Oracle 12c or above, or with rownum use a subquery -

```
select * from (
    your query here
) 
where rownum < 4;
```

Comment: I don't think using this inside plsql would matter here